# Autowired Repository updates existing entity instead of creating a new one

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

After I create first agent In country, then I can't create new agent, it's just update first agent. If I create first agent and then remove him, next agents will creates fine. I turned ON debug mode in hibernate settings so it's show that hibernate really update existing record in database instead creating new.

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface AgentsRepository extends JpaRepository<Country, Long> {
}
```

Controller

```
@Autowired
private AgentsRepository agentsRepository;

@Autowired
private CountriesRepository countriesRepository;

// Add new agent
@GetMapping("/country/{id}/agent/add")
public String addNewAgent(@PathVariable(name = "id") String countryId, Model model){
    model.addAttribute("country_id", countryId);
    model.addAttribute("agent", new Agent());
    return "agent/add";
}

@PostMapping("/country/{id}/agents/new")
public String createAgent(@PathVariable(value = "id") String countryId, @ModelAttribute Agent agent){
    return countriesRepository.findById(Long.parseLong(countryId)).map(country -> {
        agent.setCountry(country);
        agentsRepository.save(agent);
        return "redirect:/country/" + countryId + "/show/agents";
    }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("CountryId " + countryId + " not found"));
}
```

Country class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "countries")
public class Country implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull
private String name;
```

Agent class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "agents")
public class Agent implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private Long id;

@NotNull
private String status = "classified";

@NotNull
private String first_name;

@NotNull
private String last_name;

@NotNull
@Max(value = 2147483647)
private Integer documents;

@NotNull
@Max(value = 8)
private Integer people_recruited;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "country_id", nullable = false)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@JsonIgnore
private Country country;
```

Agent adding HTML

```
    <form action="#" th:action="@{'/country/{id}/agents/new'(id=${country_id})}" th:object="${agent}" method="post">
        <p>Name: <input type="text" th:field="*{first_name}" /></p>
        <p>Surname: <input type="text" th:field="*{last_name}"></p>
        <p>Documents: <input type="number" max="2147483647" th:field="*{documents}" /></p>
        <p>People recruited: <input  type="number" max="8" th:field="*{people_recruited}"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
```

Comment: `save` is probably seeing that an entity already exists with your `id`, and so is performing an update instead of inserting (since inserting would error, breaking the uniqueness of your `id` field)

Comment: make sure the `id` is unique

Comment: @Deadpool id is unique

Comment: @CollinD but I have autoincrement id, so when I create new agent it have(or should have unique id)

Comment: Please, add SQL definition of your table

Comment: I don't create tables my self, I left I to hibernate(if tables doesn't exist, hibernate create tables when you run application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@PostMapping("/country/{id}/agents/new")
public String createAgent(@PathVariable(value = "id") String countryId, @ModelAttribute Agent agent){
    return countriesRepository.findById(Long.parseLong(countryId)).map(country -> {
        Agent agentToBeSaved = new Agent();
        agentToBeSaved.setCountry(country);
        agentToBeSaved.setStatus(agent.getStatus());
        agentToBeSaved.setFirstName(agent.getFirstName());
        agentToBeSaved.setDocuments(agent.getDocuments());
        agentToBeSaved.setPeopleRecruited(agent.getPeopleRecruited());
        agentsRepository.save(agentToBeSaved);
        return "redirect:/country/" + countryId + "/show/agents";
    }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("CountryId " + countryId + " not found"));
}
```

And if it works - then you are passing some ID to Agent object from UI.

Comment: Check the place, where you sending the request. The problem is you pass an ID with your model, so hibernate updates it, instead of creating a new one. By the way, I would recommend having model classes which you recieve from the client and map them to your entities. It adds an extra layer of security and gives you a better control over your entity field values.

Comment: I check my html and didn't find anything. Also, if I create in html field like this `<input type="text" th:field="*{id}" readonly/>`(this field will read id from received model(always empty cause I request new model)) hibernate start working fine

Answer (score 0):

```
@ModelAttribute Agent agent
```

Do you pass any agentId from model (UI)?
or try setting it to null in controller.
Most probably UI is sending some dummy id for `Agent` which is same for all `Agents` Thats why JPA updates it.

Comment: nope, I pass only data to model, id generated using hibernate ``model.addAttribute("agent", new Agent());`` here I pass empty model